# Images in a flexbox doesn't scale properly

Tags: html, css

I put 2 images inside a flexbox with column direction and I want images to resize when I resize a browser window. They don't change as I expect.

I want images to change in their original ratio, but no matter what css style I use it fails.

It works fine when I resize a window horizontally buy not when I resize it vertically.

Additionally images go outside of the flexbox div, how can I prevent it?

```css
#box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: red;
}
#photo {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="container">
    <img id="photo" src="1.JPG">
    <img id="photo" src="2.JPG">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One think i normally use in this scenarios is set the image as background image using css an use `background-size:contain;`

An example:

```
#box{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: red;
}
.photo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
}



<div id="box">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="photo" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random')"></div>
    <div class="photo" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/300/200/?random')"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vbanj8st/

Comment: You can now use object fit with a polyfill so that you don't have to make it a background image

Comment: @Pete, nice tip. Didn't know it.